# React.useContext in styled function with styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I am currently using `useContext` to set the `className` in an element inside a function. For example...

```
const Wrapper = styled.header`
  background: transparent;
  &.active {
    background: black;
  }
`;

const Header = () => {
  const { isScrolling } = useContext(GlobalConsumer);
  return (
    <Wrapper className={isScrolling ? 'active' : ''}>
      Header
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

However, how can I achieve the same result but without setting `className`? For example, how can `useContext` be used inside the `styled` function as...

```
const Wrapper = styled.header`
  background: ${isScrolling ? 'black' : 'transparent'};
`;
```

Also, I want to access `const { isScrolling } = useContext(GlobalConsumer);` inside the `styled` function, not pass props from the function `Header`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don`t think you can do it inside the styled function, but at least you can change className to prop:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.header`
  background: transparent;
  ${props => props.active && css`
      background: black;
  `}
`;

const Header = () => {
  const { isScrolling } = useContext(GlobalConsumer);
  return (
    <Wrapper active={isScrolling}>
      Header
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```